# Python toolbox xml SyncOnce tag meaning

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, documentation

What does the SyncOnce tag mean?

I have a Python toolbox and this xml document was created.

**toolbox.tool.pyt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xml:lang="en">
    <Esri>
        <CreaDate>20180824</CreaDate>
        <CreaTime>13413800</CreaTime>
        <ArcGISFormat>1.0</ArcGISFormat>
        <SyncOnce>TRUE</SyncOnce>
    </Esri>
</metadata>
```

or is there a list of what all tags mean or information about the xml structure?

I know there are other tags that can go in this document like a summary tag which can be accessed/edited through the Item Description. However there is no edit section for SyncOnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just something ArcGIS uses to maintain and track changes to metadata. Nothing you need to set yourself.

According to some old docs [[1]](http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/J8690_ArcCatalog_Synchronization.pdf) and [[2]](http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/J8690_ArcCatalog_Synchronization.pdf)

> When metadata is created, the following elements are added to the ESRI
>   section, which is used by ArcCatalog to maintain metadata:
>
> - Esri/MetaID — Metadata ID (ESRI Profile)
> - Esri/CreaDate — Creation Date (ESRI Profile)
> - Esri/CreaTime — Creation Time (ESRI Profile)
> - ***Esri/SyncOnce — Synchronize Once*** (ESRI Profile)
>
> The Metadata ID element is intended to provide a unique identifier for
>   each metadata record.  Its value is a globally unique identifier
>   (GUID) that is generated by the computer.
>
> The Creation Date and Time are the date and time when the metadata
>   document was created by ArcCatalog or initialized programmatically. 
>   These values will never change. All dates and times that are written to
>   the metadata by ArcCatalog are recorded in formats that adhere to the
>   FGDC standard.  Dates are written in yyyymmdd format.Times are the
>   local time and are written in HHMMSSSS format.
>
> **The value of the Synchronize Once element will initially be "TRUE". 
>   The value "TRUE" indicates that while metadata has been created,
>   synchronization hasn't yet taken place.**

And

> Upon synchronization, SyncOnce is replaced with SyncDate and SyncTime.
>   Automatic updates and other editing operations in the User Interface,
>   or programmatically updates through the
>   IXmlPropertySetEdit::SetProperty , will add ModDate and ModTime.
>
> Anytime ArcGIS creates metadata, automatic or not, these ESRI
>   elements will be added.